# ZSH Oh-my-ZSH C-r History copying 2 characters on navigation

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, history, oh-my-zsh

When ever I use the C-r history, and use the up/down arrows (or type), the first 2 characters from the line I am interactive with seem to prepend the rest of the line (see images below). I've tried updating my ZSH, which hasn't seem to have changed anything. This did just start happening out of nowhere as well.

Not sure where to go from here, any help would be super appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing ZSH from 5.8 back down to the included 5.7.1 fixed it.